# Python DataFrame: Change status of a row in df on conditions from another df?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have two df's, One with `students attendance` and another df with `students details` records.

attendance_df

```
        name         roll        day
    0    anthony        9      2020-07-25      
    1    bruno         18      2020-09-23
    2    paul           6      2020-09-01
    3    marcus        10      2020-07-01
```

details_df

```
        name          roll     start_day     last_day
    0   anthony        9       2020-09-08    2020-09-28
    1   bruno         18       2020-09-05    2020-09-25
    2   paul           6       2020-09-01    2020-09-15
    3   marcus        10       2020-08-08    2020-09-08
```

I'm trying to get if `day` for each user is between `start_day and last_day` or not.

Ex: user - `bruno` has record in `details_df` between start_day and last_day.

Expected Output

```
        name          roll      absent
    0   anthony        9         False
    1   bruno         18         True
    2   paul           6         True
    3   marcus        10         False
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `merge`

```
out = attendance_df.merge(details_df)
out['absent'] = (df['day']>=df['start_day']) & (df['day']<=df['last_day'])
```

Comment: NOTE: For the above to work, the date columns must be of type `datetime` and **not** `string`